# Segmentation Fault when using preprocesor macro

Tags: c++, macros

I picked up a project done by another programmer in C++ under Linux and I'm trying to figure out why I get Segmentation Fault when using preprocessor macro with 16 ASCII char array but not when using less or more than 16.

The macro definition :

```
#define func(a,b) { char *p=a; char *r=b; while(*p) *p++ -= *r++; } while(0)
```

and in the code it is used like this :

```
char str1[16] = { 0xBD, 0x71, 0x27, 0xF4, 0xB1, 0x24, 0xF7, 0xA0, 0xC4, 0x78, 0x84, 0xBE, 0x79, 0xC1, 0x85, 0x39 };
char str2[19] = { 0x70, 0x06, 0xBE, 0x92, 0x7E, 0xB6, 0x8F, 0x52, 0x5D, 0x42, 0x40, 0x8A, 0x01, 0x48, 0x19, 0xCF, 0xE7, 0xF1, 0x80 };
func1(str1,str2);
```

Basically that macro shifts each character from str1 with the value of character from same position in str2. Due to the fact that it works with unsigned chars even when, by shifting, it gets negative value it returns modulus of it returning the correct char.

So the issue is not with shifting and the value obtained after shifting is with the size of the string.

If I use str1 of size 1 to 15 or 17 to 90 ASCII chars it works without any issues but when str1 is equal with 16 ASCII chars I get Segmentation fault.

I've converted the macro to a function and it works OK even with 16 ASCII chars.

Any ideas why this behavior ?

Thank you

Comment: Shouldn't str1 end in 0x0 for the iteration to end?

Comment: Don't use a macro (why would you?). If you insist: The canonical form of a multi statement macro is a `do... while` loop. The macro in your example is missing the `do`. (That should still work here though; I think dgel saw the actual segfault reason.)

Comment: Probably your compiler allocates more space for an array if it isn't a multiple of 16, and pads it with zeroes. (The code is undefined in any case unless you stick a zero in the destination array.)

Comment: All the strings used by previous programmer are not NULL terminated and the macro works fine with them, except with ones of exactly 16 chars. I've tested it with NULL terminated array and if the string is 16 chars + NULL it works and if the string is 15 char + NULL it gives Segmentation Fault.

Comment: @OctavianCiobanu Why do you say it works "fine" with them? I presume it stops even though there's no zero placed when it was coded to stop at a zero. In what sense is that fine? "It happened to do what I wanted it to do rather than what I asked it to do" is not fine.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz you pointed to something I did not check in the resulting chars ... if the last char after shift is the NULL char. I will check and get back with the result. Thank you for pointing me to something that should have been so obvious from the start.

Answer (score 3):

In spite of the first string's size you need to have '0x00' at the end of the string.